Omnistudio serverside Document Generation Images
Perhaps someone faced the following problem:
I'm trying to generate a PDF using the omnistudio documentgeneration process using Apex (server side), but I can't dynamically insert a photo from a record.
here is an example of my code:
doc template:
Signature: {{IMG_Signature}}
Apex mapping:
applicationFieldsToValue.put('Signature',application.Certification_Statement_Signature_URL__c);
Certification_Statement_Signature_URL__c - contains the url to the image file
I also tried to mat this to a formula field that displays this image (returns an IMG):
applicationFieldsToValue.put('Signature',application.Certification_Statement_Signature__c);
Maybe someone has faced something similar and knows how to solve it?
Thank you!

Server-side document generation is not supported, see here "Dynamic Images" https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=ind.doc_gen_known_limitations_in_dynamic_rich_texts__hyperlinks__and_images.htm&type=5

I'm also fairly new to OmniStudio Document Generation. I believe only the Client-Side Document Generation supports the IMG token at the moment.

You can read more about it here : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=ind.doc_gen_Client-Side_Document_Generation_Supports_Dynamic_Hyp_RT.htm&type=5

Here's the one for Server-Side : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=ind.doc_gen_Server-Side_Document_Generation_Supports_Dynamic_hyp_RT.htm&type=5
Also as a note, for the IMG token, it would need to be provided with a JSON data with this format

There's an explanation here on how to setup the IMG token : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=ind.doc_gen_dynamic_images_for_client_side_document_generation.htm&type=5
